# Retrieve server RAM usage in PERL

Tags: perl

How is it possible to retrieve the RAM usage of a server in PERL

e.g.

```
257MB / 2000MB
```

Comment: There is a "perl". There is a "Perl". There is no "PERL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Sys::Meminfo](http://p3rl.org/Sys%3a%3aMeminfo) module.